# Node / Mongoose - Multiple filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongoose

This works and filters the city for me.

```
const keyword = req.query.keyword
? {
    city: {
    $regex: req.query.keyword,
    $options: 'i',
},
: {};
```

But how can i filter for more than that?
How can i search for street and more same time? || or , not working

```
const keyword = req.query.keyword
        ? {
            city: {
              $regex: req.query.keyword,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          } || {
            street: {
              $regex: req.query.keyword,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          }
        : {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
      const keyword = req.query.keyword
        ? {
            $or: [
              {
                city: {
                  $regex: req.query.keyword,
                  $options: 'i',
                },
              },
              {
                street: {
                  $regex: req.query.keyword,
                  $options: 'i',
                },
              },
            ],
          }
        : {};
```